# New user restrictions should include blacklisted keywords and URLs

Tags: feature-request, new-users, spam

A significant portion of spam contains commonly spammed links and product names, such as:

- We*ght l*ss
- M*le enh*ncement
- B*y n*w

Almost any post containing these is spam, especially from a 1 rep user. Additionally, blocking curse words or insults could help block offensive posts. Commonly spammed product names and links should be blacklisted. Why wait for users to flag them or moderators to delete them, if you can add a content-based filter, that prevents many of such posts from being submitted in the first place?

I propose that a set of blacklisted URLs and keywords be added to the new user restrictions, so that many spammers (the vast majority of which are unregistered or 1 rep users) will be denied from submitting their post. It might happen that someone may have a valid question that happens to be about or involve one of the blacklisted words, so that's why it should be a new user restriction.

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thankfully, the spammers don't know this, but a legitimate user can easily work around these restrictions by making their post without them and then editing their post to contain them.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Also true

Comment: And then the spammers figure out how to avoid this using non-Latin characters or automated edits, meaning SE has to create a filter that catches and rejects these posts, which then generates a bunch of false positives and makes it more frustrating, less welcoming to new users. No. There are already a plethora of tools that help reduce the impact of this and that allow the community to remove the rest.

Comment: @Nij Why would new users be asking about weight loss pills or male enhancement?

Comment: Because there are several sites on the network that have weight loss questions in scope, or closely related but off-topic by policy, and anything that picks up variations of *male enhancement* will create false negatives on a number of other sites.